# How can we check (end of life) EOL of any jquery version( Ex: 3.4.0)

Tags: jquery, version, eol

Need to know EOL for jQuery version, how do we get to know the end of life?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, jQuery doesn't follow an EOL model. Instead, they say what browsers are supported by each version, what methods each version supports vs. [deprecating](https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/) vs. [removing](https://api.jquery.com/category/removed/), and have multiple branches in order to support older browsers, as you can see on their [downloading](https://jquery.com/download/) and [CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) pages.

If you raise a bug in an out-of-date version within a branch that's fixed in a later version, naturally you'll be told to update. If it's a bug in the latest stable version of and older-support branch (v1.x for instance) that's fixed in another branch, it's also possible you'll be told that it's just not worth the jQuery team spending time on (but may also be invited to do a pull request with a fix).